# How to make a bar that depletes from both sides in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

So I wanted to make a bar that depletes overtime, and I tried googling it, and I found this [smooth looking example](https://css-tricks.com/timer-bars-in-css-with-custom-properties/), but the thing is, I want the bar to deplete from both sides, so it ends up finishing in the middle. How can I do this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? You have to post some of your code in order for anyone to be able to help you.

Comment: Here is a codepen: https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/WNraewo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing you need to change in their example is `transform-origin: left center;` to `transform-origin: center;`.

Example: https://codepen.io/Bat_Cave/pen/eYjzKpr

[More on `transform-origin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).